# How to install on computer running windows XP

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

Good morning
I would like to know the easiest way to install Ubuntu alongside Windows XP on my desktop computer. 
I have a disc that I received with magazine. But I can't make it download properly.

Thanks
Greg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) How do you know that those Ubuntu installation DVDs that come with magazines like Linux Format are any good? And how do you know that they are compatible with a Windows XP computer? For this reason I am adding another link: [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own boot-able USB, just go to 
https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

You'll need to partition your HDD to install it to so you don't lose Windows! Or alternatively you can get Virtualbox. You can partition your HDD in Windows by using "Computer Management," clicking "Disk Management," and shrinking your main Windows partition so that you have the amount of Unallocated space you want for your Ubuntu installation. You can also do it in the Ubuntu Installer by clicking "Install alongside Windows" or doing a custom installation and partitioning your drive manually.